# subcaption: the subcaption documentation doesn't say anything about a short caption

Tags: captions, subcaption

When using `\subcaptionbox`, can the optional short caption be used?  By this I mean,

```
\subcaptionbox[short]{long \label{}}{\includegraphics}
```

There is nothing in the documentation that mention the use of short caption with `\subcaptionbox`.

Comment: Of course it says, on page 6 you have the syntax for `\subcaptionbox`: "`\subcaptionbox[<list entry>]{<heading>}[<width>][<inner-pos>]{<contents>}`. The arguments `<list entry>` & `<heading>` will be used for typesetting the `\caption`".

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I wasn't sure if list entry was meant to be title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is there, start by looking at page 11.  Anyway here is a working example.  As the footnote on page 3 says, you need to pass the option `list=true` to the package to get the subfigure captions in the list of figures.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox[Short subfigure title]{A long figure caption with much
  explanation}{\rule{3cm}{2cm}}\qquad
  \subcaptionbox[Short subfigure title]{A long figure caption with much
  explanation}{\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
  \caption[Figure caption]{Figure full caption}\label{fig:ex}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If it is on page 11, is it written in code?  I don't see anything mention the short title.  I looking on the documentation provided by ctan.

Comment: The is a code entry at the bottom of the page, where the optional argument contains "List-of-Figures entry".  I wouldn't call a full explanation, nor the text on page 6, just a couple of strong hints.